# How do I re-use <option> data in HTML forms? (Django) (DRY)

Tags: python, html, django, forms, dry

I'm generating an HTML response via Django with a large set of forms, and one of the form fields is a `<select>` with many (1,000+) `<option>`s in the queryset.

Due to repeating the `<option>`s for each form, the HTML response is egregiously long.  I've used pagination to reduce the amount of HTML rendered in each response, but this isn't optimal for the particular application.

Is it possible to render the `<option>`s once on the HTML response and reference it in each form field without rendering it again?

Comment: It's impossible to avoid repeating the `<option>` in pure HTML when they are needed to be referenced by the end user.

Comment: If you're option is more then *1000+* it's beter to add search options dropsown for beter user expiriance